# Sharing some data between private applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, orm, cron, rails-activerecord

I am building a Rails application that will be deployed on multiple servers, each using its own databases. Most of the data in each of these apps will be unique and private to that app.

I want to be able to share all `Posts` in each of these apps with one "daddy app" while keeping the rest of the data private. This "daddy app" will be able to query and display all `posts` collated from all the apps.

I have two ideas as to how this could potentially be done:

1. Have a separate remote database for `Posts`. This seems like it may be an issue for performance.
2. Keep all the databases local but run a cron job to sync all `Posts`.

I am not sure whether either of the above will be the best solution to this problem.

**What would be the best way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a cron approach is a good one. But instead of using a direct database connection, why not expose a JSON api where each app responds to /posts.json?since=. This way you can fetch all the latest posts to update the "daddy app"

You may also want to consider using an engine for the implementation of the Post / API so that you can share this among each rails app.

An alternative approach is to have each app submit posts to the "daddy app" as they happen (via delayed job for example).